# how to prevent istream::get() from reading additional garbage when reading extended ascii values

Tags: c++, istream

for example I have a test file that contains ÀÀ¿¿ after 4 calls to `istream::get()` i get the values (casted) values , 195, 128, 195, but also I get values like -65 -62 , which are not in the file. How do I avoid these garbage values?  test file contains : ÀÀ¿¿ÀÀ¿¿ÀÀ¿¿ÀÀ¿¿ÀÀ¿¿ÀÀ¿¿ÀÀ¿¿ÀÀ

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()

    {   
    unsigned int s = 0;
    char c;
    vector<unsigned int> v;


    ifstream is ("test.txt");
    is.seekg(0,is.end);
    int length = is.tellg();
    is.seekg(0,is.beg);
    int i = 0;
    cout<<length<<endl;
    while(i < length/2){
        is.get(c);
        i++;


        cout<<(int)c;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you post and run the code using https://ideone.com/ (replacing the file input with stdin from console) so I can get a reproducible output?

Comment: I doubt very much that the program you show us has both 195 and -65 in its output.  On common architectures, the first is possible when char is unsigned and the second when char is signed.  Could you give us a program which reproduce the result or the uncommon architecture on which you are working?

Answer (score -1):

Your file most likely contains Unicode-formatted characters. The special characters you include in the question text are not part of the ASCII table. Each Unicode character may be coded as 1 or more bytes. Reading one byte at a time (as a signed value) may yield an ASCII character if one is present or some other values related to the Unicode encoding.

See:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: UTF-8 does not explain the stated result of having both 195 and -65 in the output.

Comment: a signed char can't  hold 195, and an unsigned one can't hold -65.